# Meu Site responsivo não carrega no celular

Tags: mobile, layout-responsivo, viewport

Preciso de ajuda já tentei pesquisar em tudo que é lugar. Meu site esta responsivo (www.sdalimentos.com.br), mas quando tento carregar ele pelo celular retorna como not found. Preciso de ajuda , já coloquei a metatag viewport e nada.

Poderiam olhar e me dar uma ajuda?

Segue o meu header e o que deixa responsivo é o bootstrap que estou usando o 3.1.1. Já quando texto via extensão do Firefox ele não acha o meu viewport., não sei porque.

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SD Alimentos - salgados e doces</title>
    <meta name="description" content="O sabor dos alimentos é fator  determinante na escolha do fornecedor dos doces e salgados de sua festa, utilizamos receitas caseiras e buscamos ingredientes frescos e da melhor qualidade.">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_misc.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/testimonails-slider.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/cup_cake_icon.png" />

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Testando no meu celular, vi a mensagem de erro. No celular, ele redirecionou para uma página `index.html`. Do lado do servidor, tem algo que faz algum handling especial? Se sim, adicione o código.

Comment: Sim. Ele fica responsivo normal no navegador e no tablete, mas no celular não encontra da erro 404. Testei android, Windows phone e IOS.

Comment: Em meus celulares estão aparecendo normalmente, aparecia erro 404? O erro 404 é quando a página não no servidor, vai ver quando você enviou seu servidor demorou para fazer o upload dela e não apareceu quando você solicitava. Apague os cookies dos navegadores do celular e tente entrar novamente que aparecerá normal.